# I am asking on the logical truth of this equivalence

Tags: logic

Let us consider a mathematical statement $A(n)$ depend on a positive integer $n$. By a rigorous proof, we get that the case $A(n)$ is equivalent to $x_{n}=0$ where $x_{n}$ is a real sequence. Now, consider any positive integer $m$, then the case $A(n)$ is equivalent to $x_{n}/2^{m}=0$. So, the case $A(n)$ is equivalent to the vanishing of a sequence with a mutli-index $(n,m)$. But the index $m$ does not play any role for the case  $A(n)$.

Then I am asking on the logical truth of this equivalence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you are really using is the fact that if a number $x$ happens to be $0$ then $ax=0$ for every value of $a$.

You can then apply that  to show $x_n/2^m = 0$.